# Как выделить общую память под массив структур с динамическим массивом?

Tags: c++, opencl

У меня есть структура:

```
struct A
{
int a;
double c;
double *array;
};

main()
{
A *str = new A[50];
for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
{
   str[i].array = new double[5];
   str[i].array[0] = 50;
}

// Здесь мне необходимо создать буфер и выделить в нем память под массив
// и копировать в буфер свой массив со значениями;
Buffer BufA = (...,..., 50 * sizeof(A),str);
//Далее я буфер передаю в файл OpenCL;
//Если я инициализирую обычные переменные в массиве структур, то их я могу использовать в файле. А вот значения в динамическом массиве он не видит. Видимо я не полностью выделяю память, под динамический массив еще надо.
}
```

Можете подсказать пожалуйста, как именно надо записать память под динамический массив в общую выделяемую память? Вряд ли это специфика OpenCl, потому что я вижу значения обычных переменных. Фишка в динамическом массиве.

P.s. в принципе, я могу передать отдельно свой массив в буфер и тогда всё будет работать. Но для удобства, хотелось бы сделать это в структуре.

Answer (score 0):

Ну в структуре лежит только адрес массива. Если все массивы одинаковой длины, то так и напишите в структуре `double array[5];`

Comment: Все массивы одинаковой длины, но размер этой длины я задаю во внешнем файле, поэтому просто прописать в проекте я не могу.

Comment: Тогда придется все делать "руками". Копировать в цикле в  буфер структуру из `{int a;double c;}`, потом мавсив из нескольких `double`. Если структура передаваемого объекта определяется Вами, то лучше сначала массив из 50 структур, а потом общий массив из 50*5 значенией.  Кстати, зачем `new` используется, а не `std::vector` ?

Comment: Хм, на счет первого я не пойму, как именно. Можете написать простой пример этого? А на счет второго, я данный массив структур передаю в файл Си и там нету векторов.

Comment: Ну я просто не в курсе, как выглядит интерфейс, к которому Вы обращаетесь со сформированным буфером. И строчку `Buffer BufA = (...,..., 50 * sizeof(A),str);` я тоже не понимаю до конца, что там за типы. Обычно передается буфер для копирования, и со строны C++ там может быть `std::vector()` , точнее адрес его первого элемента.